# Restarting Shiny Server with crontab

Tags: r, shiny, cron, shiny-server

I'm having a bit of trouble getting `shiny-server` to restart via `crontab`. So far, I have tried 2 ways:

1) Created bash script with `restart shiny-server` as the last line, and added to `crontab`. Additionally, there's SQL code that pre-processes data within this script.

```
0 15 * * * bash /home/local/ANT/raybao/load.sh
```

2) Added a line to `crontab -e` for `root` user like the following:

```
0 15 * * * restart shiny-sever
```

I added to `root crontab` as opposed to my own user's simply because you need to `sudo restart shiny-server` otherwise.

Oddly, all the SQL code within #1 above successfully runs and is logged, however the `shiny-server` process is not restarted. If I simply do: `sudo -i` and then `restart shiny-server`, it works so I'm baffled.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up posting this same question on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/687423/use-crontab-to-restart-an-upstart-service-on-schedule

In summary, the correct way to schedule a restart of the `shiny-server` in Ubuntu 12.04 (which uses Upstart) is to add the following entry to your `root` user's `crontab`:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/sbin/restart shiny-server
```

Credit goes to @earthmeLon for helping me figure this out. Hope this helps somebody in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is described in the server documentation:  http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#schedulers-application-restarts

> An application can be restarted by altering the "modified time" on a file named restart.txt in the application's directory. This can most easily be done using the touch utility, as in touch restart.txt, which will update the modified timestamp on this file to the current time. Upon the next new connection to the application, Shiny Server will spawn a new R process to run the "new" (restarted) Shiny Application for this and future users. When this occurs, the old processes will remain unaltered, and open connections will remain active and valid until the last connection closes itself.

So, you could use this line to restart :

1) create a file `restart.txt` in the app directory:

```
nano restart.txt
```

2) call touch on this file:

```
* */1 * * * touch restart.txt
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I'm stil a beginner to when it comes to Linux and all that comes with it but this worked for me.

If your like me and switched from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 Ubuntu changed to use systemd as the default. This transition can also be seen [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#ubuntu-12.04) under **1.4 Stopping and Starting**.

My problem was that I had an old version of `shiny-server` that used `upstart` to start and stop shiny-server so to fix this I reinstalled shiny-server and pasted this into my crontab (root) to test if the restart worked:

```
* */1 * * * systemctl restart shiny-server
```

It sounds like your problem is different but maybe this can help somewhat?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me since I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (as mandated by corporate InfoSec team...)

Comment: That's too bad. Is there any chance that your installing the crontab for your own user? maybe you could try adding whoami > /somefile.txt to see that this is actually the case?

Comment: Nope, I'm using crontab for `root` user

Comment: and nothing in shinys log or syslog about this?